# Is there any way to Embed View in ScrollView in Xamarin Studio like Xcode

Tags: xamarin, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

As I design my layout in Xamarin Studio. But now I have problem my design structure height in more than the actual height so I want to put my `View` inside `ScrollView`.

so In Xcode we have option like  **Editor > Embed In > Scroll View**.

So Is there any option in Xamarin studio to perform the same Task.

Any Help be Appreciated.

Comment: Can't you open the View with XCode , perform the embed task and then continue with Xamarin?

Comment: @iamIcarus Thanks for the Info.